# Find control created in Code-behind using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to be able to access a label control in jQuery that was created in the codebehind.

I have added controls to my page in the codebehind like so

```
        Label L = new Label();
        L.ID = "txt" + i;
        L.Text = dr["category_name"].ToString();
        L.CssClass = "heading";
        divCat.Controls.Add(L);
```

Is it possible to find these controls via ID or an alternative option in jQuery? 
The following gives an error saying there is no such control:

```
$(function () {
  $(".hoverlabel").hover(function () {
    $("#<%=txt1.ClientID %>").show();
  });

});
```

Comment: Inspect your source code, see what is your label ID, in the client, and see the result of your <%=%> fragment.

Comment: probably easier to use a traverse and not worry about using server code to fill in selector... show some source html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure will it work or not.
You can take the benefit of the `ClientIDMode="Static"`
eg.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEcho2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

In your case

```
    Label L = new Label();
    L.ID = "txt" + i;
    L.Text = dr["category_name"].ToString();
    L.CssClass = "heading";
    divCat.Controls.Add(L); 
    L.ClientIDMode= ClientIDMode.Static;
```

and your jquery function

```
    $(function () {
        $(".hoverlabel").hover(function () {
        $("#txt1").show();
       });
    });
```

Comment: This correct syntax is L.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;

When changed to that, this works great thanks!

Comment: @AzaRoth91 thanks for the correction. And you are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do.. that way.

You're trying to use a string as an object within code. Take this normal C# for example:

```
string myString = "HelloString";
string lowerString = HelloString.ToLower(); // This won't work..
```

That is the equivalent of what you're trying to do.

The workaround is using `FindControl`:

```
$(function () {
    $(".hoverlabel").hover(function () {
        $("#<%= FindControl("txt1").ClientID %>").show();
    });
});
```

This will find a control based on the ID you've dynamically assigned it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code-behind actually renders an html `<label>`, your jQuery could be something like:

```
$(function () {
  $(".hoverlabel").hover(function () {
    $("label.heading").show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign an additional "identifying CSS class":

```
var L = new Label();
L.ID = "txt" + i;
L.Text = dr["category_name"].ToString();
L.CssClass = "heading myLabel"; // Set multiple classes separated by spaces
divCat.Controls.Add(L);
```

Then you can get your control with this jQuery statement:

```
$(function () {
  $(".hoverlabel").hover(function () {
    $(".myLabel").show();
  });
});
```